# JAVA. проблема с методом DataInputStream.read()

Tags: java

Нужно из файла x.txt прочитать меньше 8 байт (неполный long) и записать их последовательно в long T, оставшаяся часть Т заполняется нулями. 
Прочитал, записал, и в выходном файле получились непонятно откуда взятые биты...

```
FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream("x.txt");
FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream("y.txt");

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputFile);   
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outputFile);    

long T = 0;

//сдвигаем каждый байт к "своему" месту в Т
for (int i = 0; i < dis.available(); i++) {
    T += (long)(dis.readByte()) << (7 - i)*8; 
}

dos.writeLong(T);
```

Comment: *метод readBytes()

Comment: попробуйте `T += (readByte() & 0xFFL) << (7 - i)*8;`, в java байт - знаковый, при расширении до long "отрицательного байта" старшие разряды добиваются единицами.

Comment: @zRrr , спасибо, помогло))

Comment: @zRrr 
плюс моя ошибка в строке 
     for (int i = 0; i < dis.available(); i++). 
dis.available() - уменьшается с каждой итерацией..часть байтов просто не читались..